# What is an in-depth ASP.NET book?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm wondering what a good book to read describing how ASP.NET works.  I'm thinking something similar to CLR via C# but focused on ASP.NET.

**Clarification:** I'm interested in ASP.NET as a platform including things like httphandlers, httpmodules, state management (SessionStateModule), and caching.  I'm not looking for information on Visual Studio, ADO.NET, XML, or specific controls.

What do you recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought Matthew MacDonald's *Pro ASP.NET 2.0 in C# 2005* covered the topic well, and it looks like the 'sequel' would be his *[Pro ASP.NET 3.5 in C# 2008, Second Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590598938)*.  I would recommend it for your review.

Comment: This book is really great. It must be on the shelf of any wanna-be-good asp.net developer.

Comment: I also use this book, it's the best one that I have found so far.

Comment: Cool.  I'll snag the 2009 edition: http://www.amazon.com/Pro-ASP-NET-3-5-2008-Silverlight/dp/1430215674/ref=reg_hu-wl_item-added

Answer (score 1):

Check out ASP.NET unleashed:
[http://www.amazon.com/ASP-NET-3-5-Unleashed-Stephen-Walther/dp/0672330113/ref=pd_cp_b_01](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672330113)

[ASP.NET Unleashed http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/21DEAJ2Ny-L._BO2,204,203,200_PIsitb-sticker-arrow-click,TopRight,35,-76_AA198_SH20_OU01_.jpg](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/21DEAJ2Ny-L._BO2,204,203,200_PIsitb-sticker-arrow-click,TopRight,35,-76_AA198_SH20_OU01_.jpg)

*edit: oops, I had originally linked to the old version of the book.  here's the latest :-)*

Comment: I've not read that one, but I have read a lot of Stephen Walther 1stuff, and he is very good. +1

Comment: I found this book merely just a reference book for developers, it does not get you to the depth.